# Remove local icloud files from device?

Tags: ios, objective-c, file, icloud, nsfilemanager

on the first install application on device and when read content of icloud file the checking of file is true:

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[fileURL path]]
```

but I can not read the contents befor not yet downloaded the file to the device:

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] startDownloadingUbiquitousItemAtURL:fileURL error:nil];
```

after all operation with file i want remove local copy file from device, but not remove this file from icloud.
Where these copies are stored and you can remove them?
NSURL to the copies must be different NSURL icloud. if they match then I'll delete the file in icloud.

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the local copy without deleting the file from iCloud using the following call.

`[[NSFileManager defaultManager] evictUbiquitousItemAtURL:fileUrl error:nil];`

Answer (score 1):

If the path you are using is the ubiquity container then files are synchronised automatically so deleting a file will result in the iCloud file also being removed.  If you want to keep a local copy you need to copy the file to a the apps local sandbox directory, so first start the download and once that is complete then copy the file to the local directory or to a .nosync subdirectory in the ubiquity container.

The purpose of the iCloud container is for syncing file not for Cloud storage.

Comment: I have for example: download file (backup file) - read and file is no longer needed on the device.
To read this is file  I don't need to copy it to another location.
I am afraid that this will grow the size of the apps local sandbox directory.
The question is: can be remove synchronized files without removing this is files from the iCloud?

Comment: I think you are out of luck.  Something like Dropbox might be a better option